# php 7 on Ubuntu not installing

Tags: php, ubuntu, php-7

I'm trying to install a LAMP environment on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS by following [this](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-apache-with-php-and-mysql-on-ubuntu-16-04-lamp/) tutorial. However, right in the first steps I'm getting errors about PHP 7:

```
Setting up grub-pc (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.15) ...
dpkg: error processing package grub-pc (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
Setting up unattended-upgrades (0.90ubuntu0.9) ...
dpkg: error processing package unattended-upgrades (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
Setting up php7.0-common (7.0.27-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
dpkg: error processing package php7.0-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.0-readline:
 php7.0-readline depends on php7.0-common (= 7.0.27-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1); however:
  Package php7.0-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.0-readline (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.0-opcache:
 php7.0-opcache depends on php7.0-common (= 7.0.27-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1); however:
  Package php7.0-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.0-opcache (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.0:
 php7.0 depends on php7.0-common; however:
  Package php7.0-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libapache2-mod-php7.0:
 libapache2-mod-php7.0 depends on php7.0-common (= 7.0.27-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1); however:
  Package php7.0-common is not configured yet.
 libapache2-mod-php7.0 depends on php7.0-opcache; however:
  Package php7.0-opcache is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-php7.0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.0-cli:
 php7.0-cli depends on php7.0-common (= 7.0.27-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1); however:
  Package php7.0-common is not configured yet.
 php7.0-cli depends on php7.0-opcache; however:
  Package php7.0-opcache is not configured yet.
 php7.0-cli depends on php7.0-readline; however:
  Package php7.0-readline is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.0-cli (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.0-json:
 php7.0-json depends on php7.0-common (= 7.0.27-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1); however:
  Package php7.0-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.0-json (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-pc
 unattended-upgrades
 php7.0-common
 php7.0-readline
 php7.0-opcache
 php7.0
 libapache2-mod-php7.0
 php7.0-cli
 php7.0-json
```

I've been searching and found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/752397/error-the-new-file-usr-lib-php-7-0-php-ini-production-cli-does-not-exist) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/896706/getting-errors-while-installing-phpmyadmin-in-ubuntu-16-04) solutions, but none of them worked for me. What else can I try?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "In the first steps" - so where? Step 1 is installing MySQL, step 3 would be installing PHP, so you mean after execution of the first command of step 3?

Comment: @MichaelB. Sorry, after the execution of the command of installing MySQL.

Comment: have you had PHP already installed or could it be you already installed LAMP during the ubuntu installation? At that position no PHP should been installed. Have you run apt update && apt upgrade, are there any problems?

Comment: @MichaelB., I unistalled php and tried to run again the MySQl install command. The list of errors got shorter:

Comment: The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apache2-data apache2-utils
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up unattended-upgrades (0.90ubuntu0.9) ...
dpkg: error processing package unattended-upgrades (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 unattended-upgrades

Comment: When I run apt upgrade the errors are the same

Comment: Have you tried that: 'sudo apt autoremove', like the error have suggested. Then run apt update && apt upgrade again. A reboot could help sometimes too...
But, when I'm running in too much errors at that point, a clean new installation have helped wonders, as trying everything that could be found in any forum had killed the ubuntu way to often.